# ansible find a folder in a path that does not contain a certain subfolder fails

Tags: ansible

I have folders like on my target host:

> /home/admin/stream
>
> /home/admin/STB/stream/data_en
>
> /home/admin/STB_1/stream

I search based on stream in /home/admin but need only folders that does not have data_en in it..

What i tried:

Find directories where stream is present with ansbile code

```
  - name: Find all folders with stream subfolder in it
    find:
     paths: /home/admin/stream
     file_type: directory
     pattern: 'stream'
     use_regex: no
     recurse: yes
    register: files_to_change

  - name: rename folders
    command: mv "{{ item['path'] }}" "{{ item['path'] }}.disable"
    with_items: "{{ files_to_change.files }}"
    when: 
       - item['path'] is not regex(item['path']/data_en)
```

I am trying to rename only folder 1 and 3 from the below list, because folder 2 has data_en inside it.

1. /home/admin/stream
2. /home/admin/STB/stream
3. /home/admin/STB_1/stream

I could not figure out a way to skip that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and [test](https://pythex.org/) the condition, e.g.

```yaml
    when: item.path is not regex('^(.*)/data_en(.*)$')
```

You might want to test the code first, e.g.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg:  "mv {{ item.path }} {{ item.path }}.disable"
    loop: "{{ files_to_change.files }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.path }}"
    when: item.path is not regex('^(.*)/data_en(.*)$')
```

should give

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/home/admin/stream) => 
  msg: mv /home/admin/stream /home/admin/stream.disable
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/home/admin/STB/stream/data_en) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=/home/admin/STB_1/stream) => 
  msg: mv /home/admin/STB_1/stream /home/admin/STB_1/stream.disable
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I am facing the below error.

ERROR! 'label' is not a valid attribute for a LoopControl

i am using ansible 2.1.1 version

may be it is a version issue?

Is it possible to achieve the samething using 'with_items'?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use Ansible 2.1 anymore. May I suggest you try it on your own? Remove `loop_control` and `label`.